# How to create a non cumulative version of sleep() in Python

Tags: python, sleep, pause

Please, accept my apologies for the delayed feedback. It was impossible before.

I'll explain it better.

I've built a Midi - OSC control surface for Reaper in Python. It receives and sends OSC messages.

I use UP and DOWN arrows on the keyboard to move through tracks in Reaper. I can move very fast through tracks until I find the one I want to stay on. Then, my script sends a OSC message to receive everything from Reaper using PythonOSC.

I will explain using code.

That function receives OSC messages (e.g.: `/track/volume`, etc.) Each time the client receives `/select`, it tells my script that a track changed in Reaper.

```py
def OSC(self, *args):
    s = re.search(r'/track/(.+)', args[0])
    if s:
        if s.group(1) == 'select' and args[1] == 0:
        """I want that next line to be executed only when about 0.5 second had passed
        since the last time it enters that point. It is to avoid that PythonOSC sends
        that line 10 times in 1 second and overloads the process."""
            client.send_message('/device/track/follows/last_touched', 1)
```

I imagined something like that but I don't know if it's overkill, if I miss something.

1. Each time I press up or down, a timer starts in a thread or something. It resets each time.
2. When I land on my track, the timer continues until `0.5` second and then, launches my `client.send_message()` line.

Is it too much? The thing is, a thread will still have to be killed or something. I'm very new to Python.

The example given, with the decorator is great but it activates the function (in my case, it's finally only a line of code) when it's triggred within 0.5 second while I want it to be triggered after a 0.5 second pause following the last time it's called.

Note: I realize that my code example is all sent in a block in the preview box. I indented it but it breaks it. I'm very sorry for that, I can't see the option I need to use.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'cumulative'? It's not clear to me at the moment.

Comment: It's hard to imagine "cumulative" sleep. If executing this abstract *function* took 0.17 seconds, you want to "sleep" 0,33 seconds after, am I understood you properly?

Comment: Please show actual code that you actually wrote, and explain what it does, and how that is different from what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Does your function receive commands asynchronously? I mean, is it possible that this function (`OSC()`) will be executed parallel and, if yes, does this "delay" have to be shared between all instances which execute this function?

Comment: That function is completely autonomous. It receives data from OSC and interpret it but no need to be synchronized with anything else.

Comment: @Betov75, additional details would really help to give you more precise answer. Generally, you need to use mutex to let only one instance execute this code, in python there's separate locks for threading synchronization ([`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock)) and for multiprocessing ([`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock)), so you should use one which fits method of concurrency your program use. You can add name of module you're using or any other information which add clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I've interpreted your question correctly, but if you're trying to make function execution to take *not less* than provided time, you can use this decorator

```py
from time import time, sleep

def timed(time_to_sleep):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            start_time = time()
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            time_to_sleep_left = time_to_sleep - (time() - start_time)
            if time_to_sleep_left > 0:
                sleep(time_to_sleep_left)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```py
@timed(0.5)
def test():
    pass
```